# Store diskspace in a file

Tags: javascript, linux, file, mongodb, diskspace

Hello I have a javascript file, that stores data in the mongodb. I would like to do two things

1) ask for the diskspace due to "db.mycol.stats();" or something like that and store the used storage size (should be "size" or storage size") into a var.

2) I want to store that var in a file - like e.g. .txt

I saw and used the following: (disksapce is an array with different disksizes, I would like to measure, (amount is a var))

```
var fso2 = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var b = fso2.CreateTextFile(file_diskspace, true);


    for (m=0;m<diskspace.length;m++)
    {
        b.WriteLine(amount+ ":" + diskspace[m]+"\n");
    }

 b.Close();
```

somehow this does not work.
(I'm using a linux server)

Comment: ActiveX is an MS technology, doesn't exist on Linux.

Comment: hm oh, okay^^ - what would I do for linux? :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various reasons why this won't work. You can't typically write files from within a JS context (certainly not from within MongoDB's), ActiveXObject only exists on windows.

If you want to do this write the script by invoking print`(db.getSiblingDB("yourDb").stats().storageSize);` and writing to a file (or piping the output to a file)

EDIT : Like so : `mongo --quiet --eval "db.getSiblingDB('test').stats().storageSize" > size.text`

Comment: so i insert into my script "(db.getSiblingDB("yourDb").runCommand( { collStats: "yourCollection" } ).storageSize);"  without --eval? How would I wirte the output in a file in linux?

Comment: Not without eval. That's why you use runCommand so you don't need the mongodb environment itself : mongo --quiet --eval "db.getSiblingDB('test').runCommand( { collStats: 'test' } ).storageSize" > size.text

Comment: ah okay - Is there a way to run that command via the .js? I'm inserting data in several steps for benchmarking - so after each iteration I would like to check the storagesize - - the > size.text isn't the command for piping the result into the text - it's just a symbol of that process, isn't it?

Comment: it's not true that you can't run db.<collection>.stats() from --eval

Comment: True, I just tested it. Not sure why I thought this was the case but I've modified my answer. Thanks!

Comment: it's true that you can't do commands like "use dbname" so you have to connect to appropriate DB: mongo server:port/dbname --quiet --eval xxx if you want to use "db.xxx" type commands

Comment: so I can include e.g. "db.mycol.stats();" into my script? and bind the output like the size/storagesize to a variabel?

Comment: so I can include e.g. "db.mycol.stats();" into my script? and bind the output like the size/storagesize to a variabel?